# How can I stretch the height using GetSkeleton framework

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, frameworks

I am using the GetSkeleton CSS framework to build my website and I've broken it down in currently 3 sections. I have my header which contains my navigation and a logo. Then underneath I have my main content which is split into 2, as Skeleton uses columns I have a sidebar which is two columns and my main section is ten columns. How can I stretch my sidebar and main section to 100% height? I don't want any footers or anything, just 100% height from those sections?

[Example of Website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONYjk.png)

Above is a screen shot of my website so far, so you can see I want that red and blue to stretch right to the bottom of the website.

This is the framework I'm using: http://getskeleton.com

And here is my HTML code;

```
<!-- Primary Page Layout
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
<div class="container u-full-width">

<div style="padding: 10px;">

  <div class="row">
    <!-- Navigation Bar -->
    <div class="twelve columns">
      <?php include 'includes/navbar.php'; ?>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row" style="padding-top: 5%;">
    <!-- Side Bar -->
    <div class="two columns link-coloured" style="background-color: blue;">  
      <h2>Customers</h2>
      <hr>
      <br /><br />
      <h5><a href="#">Live Leads</a> (3)</h5>
      <h5><a href="#">Action Required </a><span style="color: red;">(5)</span></h5>
      <h5><a href="#">Notifications </a><span style="color: orange;">(2)</span></h5>
      <h5><a href="#">New Leads </a><span style="color: green;">(11)</span></h5>
    </div>
    <!-- Main Content Section -->
    <div class="ten columns" style="background-color: red;">
      <h1>Live Leads</h1>
      <hr>
      <button class="button-primary">Add New Lead</button>
      <br /><br />
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>Customer Name</th>
            <th>Date Added</th>
            <th>Status</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Name 2</td>
            <td>08/09/2019</td>
            <td><span style="color: green">Vehicle Sold</span></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Name 3</td>
            <td>09/07/2019</td>
            <td><span style="color: blue">Prospect</span></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>name 4</td>
            <td>10/07/2019</td>
            <td><span style="color: red">Archived</span></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Please add `<div class="container">` above class="row"

Comment: I had added it, not sure why it didn't show it but it should show it now

Answer (score 0):

I think This will be working fine

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>tt</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="skeleton.css">
</head>
<body>
<div style="padding: 10px;">

<div class="row">
  <!-- Navigation Bar -->
  <div class="twelve columns">
    <?php include 'includes/navbar.php'; ?>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row" style="padding-top: 5%; ">
  <!-- Side Bar -->
  <div class="two columns link-coloured" style="background-color: blue; height: calc(100vh - 140px)">  
    <h2>Customers</h2>
    <hr>
    <br /><br />
    <h5><a href="#">Live Leads</a> (3)</h5>
    <h5><a href="#">Action Required </a><span style="color: red;">(5)</span></h5>
    <h5><a href="#">Notifications </a><span style="color: orange;">(2)</span></h5>
    <h5><a href="#">New Leads </a><span style="color: green;">(11)</span></h5>
  </div>
  <!-- Main Content Section -->
  <div class="ten columns" style="background-color: red;height: calc(100vh - 140px)">
    <h1>Live Leads</h1>
    <hr>
    <button class="button-primary">Add New Lead</button>
    <br /><br />
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Customer Name</th>
          <th>Date Added</th>
          <th>Status</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Name 2</td>
          <td>08/09/2019</td>
          <td><span style="color: green">Vehicle Sold</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Name 3</td>
          <td>09/07/2019</td>
          <td><span style="color: blue">Prospect</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>name 4</td>
          <td>10/07/2019</td>
          <td><span style="color: red">Archived</span></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Venkat, however that didn't work. I've updated my question with more of my code so you can see exactly what i'm using

Comment: Update My comment sorry for the late replay

Comment: Please check that new You have to use height : calc(100vh - 100px)